# Omit first plot from a dropdown list in R Markdown using plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown

I'm creating an HTML file with RMarkdown that contain's some interactive plots. With some help, I got to create a dropdown list to filter a variable that changes the plot. I want to do 2 things:

First, I want the year of "2023" to appear as the first plot. Secondly, I would like to omit the first plot that appears with all the years and months grouped.

The code I'm working with:

```
data <- data.frame(
  anoobito = sample(2019:2023),
  diadasemana = sample(c("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",
                         "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"), 23000, replace = TRUE)
)

mes <- data %>%
  group_by(anoobito, MES_OBITO) %>%
  tally %>%
  mutate(MES_OBITO = factor(MES_OBITO, levels = c("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril",
                                                  "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"))) %>%
  rename("Mês" = "MES_OBITO",
         "Ano do Óbito" = "anoobito")


fig <- mes |> 
  plot_ly(x = ~Mês, 
          y = ~n, 
          split = ~`Ano do Óbito`,
          type = 'bar',
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          textposition = "none",
        text = ~paste('</br> Ano do Óbito: ', `Ano do Óbito`,
                      '</br> Mês do Óbito: ', Mês,
                      '</br> Óbitos: ', n))|> 
  layout(width = 820, 
         xaxis = list(title = "Mês do Óbito", linecolor = 'black'),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'Número de Óbitos', showgrid = F, zeroline = T,
                      linecolor = 'black', range = c(0, max(mes$n)+10)),
          colorway = c("#4567a9", "#118dff", "#107dac", "#1ebbd7", "#064273", "#71c7ec"),
         showlegend = T,
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2019"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2020"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2021"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2022"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2023")
               
             )
           )
         ) ,
         margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0, pad = 0),  # Adjusted to remove margins
         xaxis = list(
           showline = TRUE,  # Added to show x-axis line
           showgrid = FALSE   # Added to hide x-axis grid
         )
  )

fig
```

When I knit it to HTML, the first plot that appears is the one below:

[image]

Is there any way I can omit this first plot and only the show the respective plot for each year when selecting the year on the dropdown menu?

Comment: A couple of initial thoughts: (1) for the first initial plot, you can use the `active` argument in `updatemenus` and set to 4 (5th plot, zero-indexed), for example: `updatemenus = list(list(active = 4, buttons = list(...` and (2) to omit the first grouped plot, you might want to separate out the 5 plot years in plotly; if you did that, you can make `visible = "legendonly"` for 4 of the 5 plots as you have now, then add the 5th plot which would be visible...

Comment: @Ben the active part worked, now 2023 appears as the default selection in the dropdown menu, but I didn't get the visible = "legendonly" part. I set all of the years (but 2023) with "legendonly", but the grouped plot keeps appearing, even when I select the year in the dropdown menu.

Comment: See below answer for example that will show 2023 alone using `visible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a specific initial plot, use `active` argument in `updatemenus`. In this case, use 4 (zero-indexed from 0-4 corresponding to 2019 to 2023).

To show initial bar plot, would divide up your plots and use `add_bars`. Here you can set `visible` to `FALSE` for years 2019 to 2022, and `TRUE` for 2023.

```
mes |> 
  plot_ly(hoverinfo = 'text',
          textposition = "none",
          text = ~paste('</br> Ano do Óbito: ', `Ano do Óbito`,
                        '</br> Mês do Óbito: ', Mês,
                        '</br> Óbitos: ', n)) |> 
  add_bars(data = mes[mes$`Ano do Óbito` %in% 2019:2022,],
           x = ~Mês, 
           y = ~n, 
           split = ~`Ano do Óbito`,
           visible = F) |>
  add_bars(data = mes[mes$`Ano do Óbito` == 2023,],
           x = ~Mês, 
           y = ~n, 
           split = ~`Ano do Óbito`,
           visible = T) |>
  layout(width = 820, 
         xaxis = list(title = "Mês do Óbito", linecolor = 'black'),
         yaxis = list(side = 'left', title = 'Número de Óbitos', showgrid = F, zeroline = T,
                      linecolor = 'black', range = c(0, max(mes$n)+10)),
         colorway = c("#4567a9", "#118dff", "#107dac", "#1ebbd7", "#064273", "#71c7ec"),
         showlegend = F,
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             active = 4,
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2019"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2020"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2021"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "2022"),
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)),
                    label = "2023")
               
             )
           )
         ) ,
         margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, b = 0, t = 0, pad = 0),  # Adjusted to remove margins
         xaxis = list(
           showline = TRUE,  # Added to show x-axis line
           showgrid = FALSE   # Added to hide x-axis grid
         )
  )
```